¿Cómo puedo resolver el error relacionado con las dependencias de Gradle al intentar ejecutar react-native run-android?
Estoy enfrentando un problema al tratar de ejecutar react-native run-android en mi proyecto de React Native. El error que recibo está relacionado con las dependencias de Gradle y se ve así:

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
